# How to get Method call with request parameter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, dart, https, dart-pub

How can I use the get method with the request parameter and header in a flutter, I have used the  https://pub.dev/packages/http for calling Get API.

```
response=await _client.get(Uri.http(url, payload),headers: header);
```

> Error:- [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled
> Exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
>
> E/flutter ( 2603): //demo.test/text/public/user/user_list
>
> E/flutter ( 2603): ^

Comment: Would you share url and payload?

Comment: @KuKu Thanks for the response, Sorry I can't share the URL.

Comment: what is _client variable? Please add variables to describe the complete problem

Comment: An example get request would look something like this: `response = await http.get('$url');` with the import statement as `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`

Comment: var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse(url));

    request.body =payload;

    request.headers.addAll(header);


    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();


    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      print(await response.stream.bytesToString());

    }

    else {

      print(response.reasonPhrase);

    }

I have fixed my issue with the above code but the response is not converted in Map data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here may be payload that you are trying to send, get method in the http library does not support such a thing. So use post method instead if you need to send data to the server. I had the same issue some time ago and I found that creators of this library are very strict on purposes of each of the methods.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. please check the below the comment for solution